# How do I change the installed version of Lua (Windows 10)

Tags: lua

Trying to get to grips with LuaDist.

Followed the instructions at https://github.com/LuaDist/Repository/wiki/LuaDist%3A-Installation and got as far as testing the installation by building a new deployment using:

```
cd _install\bin
luadist C:\my_lua install lua luasocket md5
cd C:\my_lua\bin
lua -e "require 'md5'"
```

However I get the following error message:

```
Finding out available versions of lua...
Getting lua-5.3.2 (source)...
Finding out available versions of luasocket...
Getting luasocket-3.0-rc1 (source)...
 - trying another candidate due to: Error getting dependency of 'luasocket-3.0-rc1': Package 'lua >=5.1,<5.3' needed, but selected at version '5.3.2'.
Getting luasocket-2.1-dev (source)...
 - trying another candidate due to: Error getting dependency of 'luasocket-2.1-dev': Package 'lua >=5.1,<5.3' needed, but selected at version '5.3.2'.
Getting luasocket-2.0.2 (source)...
 - trying another candidate due to: Error getting dependency of 'luasocket-2.0.2': Package 'lua ~>5.1' needed, but selected at version '5.3.2'.
Getting luasocket-scm (source)...
Cannot install package 'luasocket': Error getting dependency of 'luasocket-3.0-rc1': Package 'lua >=5.1,<5.3' needed, but selected at version '5.3.2'.
```

So I googled around and found this page: https://github.com/LuaDist/Repository/issues/221

Which says that lua 5.3.2 is not yet supported and that the workaround is to use lua 5.2

So, with utmost optimism I blindly ran the command that he suggested:

```
luadist.exe c:\lua52 install lua-5.2 luasec
```

And it gave me the following message:

```
C:\TDM-GCC-64\_bootstrap\_install\bin>luadist.exe c:\lua52 install lua-5.2
Finding out available versions of lua...
Getting lua-5.2 (source)...
Building lua-5.2...
Installation successful.
```

But when I go back to running my original commands to test the deployment (as above) I get the same dependency error as above.

What do I need to do to get my LuaDist to switch from 5.3.2 to 5.2?

**Edit**: Hmm, just realised I actually missed off `luasec` from his command. So no idea what I've done now...

For what it's worth running his command correctly gives:

```
C:\TDM-GCC-64\_bootstrap\_install\bin>luadist.exe c:\lua52 install lua-5.2 luasec
Finding out available versions of luasec...
Getting luasec-0.4 (source)...
Finding out available versions of luasocket...
Getting luasocket-2.0.2 (source)...
 - trying another candidate due to: Error getting dependency of 'luasec-0.4': Error getting dependency of 'luasocket-2.0.2': Package 'lua ~>5.1' needed, but installed at version '5.2'.
Getting luasec-scm (source)...
Finding out available versions of luasocket...
Getting luasocket-2.0.2 (source)...
 - trying another candidate due to: Error getting dependency of 'luasocket-2.0.2': Package 'lua ~>5.1' needed, but installed at version '5.2'.
Getting luasocket-2.0.2 (source)...
Cannot install package 'luasec': Error getting dependency of 'luasec-0.4': Error getting dependency of 'luasocket-2.0.2': Package 'lua ~>5.1' needed, but installed at version '5.2'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luadist is based on Lua 5.1 (some modules can work with 5.2 or 5.3) .. Try to use lua 5.1

luadist.exe c:\lua51 install lua-5.1.5 luasec

Comment: Thanks, will try this